# Aws : get bounced email address with laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-sns

i need to get bounced email list from aws using laravel.

i have created topic and subscription but unable to make subscription confirm. Everytime i am getting below error while trying to confirm the subscription ,

1 validation error detected: Value null at 'token' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 8138509a-301b-5a9f-94b6-01e8b8389299) tried by creating aws topic and subscription with public URL but unable to get bounced email ids.

i have refer below code to get bounced email list,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html#configure-feedback-notifications-console

Anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: If you created an SNS topic for bounce notifications, then your question doesn't make sense.  That's how you do it.  What do you mean "unable to get?"

Comment: yes we created topic and subscription but unable to make subscription confirm.Everytime i am getting below error while trying to confirm the subscription   ,                                                                                                   
 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'token' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 8138509a-301b-5a9f-94b6-01e8b8389299)

Comment: Ah, okay, so the real issue is that you are having difficulty with the subscription confirmation.  Please revise the question so that it reflects the actual problem, and show the code you are using.  Create a new subscription and log the output along with the confirmation request.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I have edited my question..hope now will get some solution !!! :)